# PHP login form - prevent direct access to page2

Tags: php

I created a PHP multi-user login form, everything seems to be working fine: I have a page with a form, upon successful login it redirects to page2 just as it should. But I have a problem: that page2 can also be accessed directly if anyone knows the URL. How can I prevent direct access and redirect users back to page1 with the login form if they try to access that page2 directly? Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried on page2:

```
/* hoped that it would check whether form button was pressed on page1 */
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
?>
// html code for page2 here, followed by:
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: By checking the session, does the user have the right permissions? - no -> block access | yes -> allow access

Comment: Create a controller or routing and create roles and permissions

Comment: could you pls give a code sample for this, coz I do get the logic, but don't know how to write it.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise

Comment: ^.. and we also can't code from scratch for ya. Try posting some code and we will help you out.

Comment: @MehdiBounya - I provided a sample of what I did. Can you explain what is wrong with that? My code was supposed to check at the top of the file whether the form button was pressed on page1 - if(isset($_POST['submit'])) - all of the page2 is within this if statement. In other words, if the button on the form was not pressed then it should skip page2 code and do else statement which redirects back to page1. But this is not working. So can you help?

Comment: Sure.Your implementation of "permissions check" is invalid, imagine if a user creates a dummy form with a `submit` named button in your website (which he can do in his browser) and click on it. Will the code you provided allow him to access the page or not?

Comment: ok i guess that makes sense. but how do i resolve? I attempted if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) - but that did not work either. I really don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Edit your question with what the code where you check for permission, also do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` and post the result in your quesion.

Comment: well, sorry everyone - turns out, if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) actually worked!